# How to replace a string with star except first character in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, replace

I want to know how can I replace a given string with stars except first character of string in kotlin

For e.g i have string "Rizwan" , I want it to be R*****

Comment: `s[0] + "*".repeat(s.length - 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [`padEnd()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-end.html):

```
val name = "Rizwan"
val newName = name[0].toString().padEnd(name.length, '*')
```

Result:

```
"R*****"
```

Comment: All the methods including this works perfectly but this one is easy one to implement

Comment: Thank you soo much

Answer (score 2):

Try replace center of String like Phone number. with `★`:

```
phone.replaceRange(2 , phone.length-3 , "★".repeat(phone.length-5))
```

pay attention to `2 + 3 = 5` :D

**Result:**

"09★★★★★229"

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `(?<=.).` with `*`:

```
val input = "Rizwan"
val output = input.replace(Regex("(?<=.)."), "*")
println(output)
```

This prints:

```
R*****
```

The lookbehind `(?<=.)` in the regex pattern ensures that we only replace a character if at least one character precedes it.  This spares the first character from being replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in Kotlin so this may not be the best way to do it but it will work for sure.

```
var s = "Rizwan"

    var l = s.length

    val first = s[0]
    s=""
    while(l>1) {
        s=s+"*"
        l--
    }

    s=first+s

    print(s)
```

Basic Algorithm..... using no library or functions

Comment: I'm guessing you come from a C background. :D

Comment: Yes It works but can you explain in details how it's working. I can't understand the flow but yes it's working

Answer (score 1):

val name = "Rizwan"
val newName = name[0].toString().padEnd(name.length, '*')

**Result:**

"R*****"